# How to configure Wildfly JMS connection factory and destination

Tags: jms, glassfish-4, wildfly-8

I have migrated recently from Glassfish 4 to Wildfly 8.1

I have configured JMS Connection Factory and Destination in Glassfish as:

```
connection factory------------------------------
jndi name: emailConnectionFactory
resource type: javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory

destination ------------------------------------
jndi name: emailQueue
resource type: javax.jms.Queue
```

In Wildfly I go to Configuration->Messaging->Destinations->Connection Factories and enter values name and jndi name as above. but it tells me that jndi name must start from 'java:/' or 'java:jboss/'.
I tried to use jndi name as 'java:/ConnectionFactory' and destination and in Configuration->Messaging->Destinations->queue/topics jndi name as 'java:/jms/queue/emailQueue'

but it didnt gave me and exception and didnt send email with previous email setting

Answer (score 1):

Do the same configuration in standalone-full.xml file .
[link1](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration)

[link2](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/how-to-code-a-remote-jms-client-for-wildfly-8)

Answer (score 0):

cool. our team is also doing the same thing - migrating a huge glassfish4 app to wildfly.

Keep this in mind,

1. For connection factory must be prefixed with java:/ or
   java:jboss/exported/ (for remote access).
2. For queues and topics, use the same rule. Any jms-queue or jms-topic which needs to be
   accessed by a remote client needs to have an entry in the
   "java:jboss/exported" namespace.